# Vs code remote container not stopping on breakpoints

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

I have a setup with both a devcontainer.json and a launch.json with the new Remote Container plugin in vs-code. But I cant get the breakpoints working. I get the app to launch and can browse it, but the breakpoints are not getting hit, am I missing something in my launch.json?

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
                "0.0.0.0:8000",
            ],
            "env": {
                "PYTHONUNBUFFERED": 1,
                "ENV": "local",
                "DJANGO_SITE_ID": 1,
                "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE": "project.settings.local1",
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration has diverged from the default `launch.json` config for Django and is missing some critical parts (it looks like everything that's missing is important):

```
    {
        "name": "Python: Django",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "args": [
            "runserver",
            "--noreload",
            "--nothreading"
        ],
        "django": true
},
```

Comment: This was indeed correct, and its now working. Why is --noreload a must to get this to work? Is there any other steps that can be taken to get automatic reloading?

Comment: We're working on getting it to work (it's complicated due to Django creating new processes and thus detecting that and then attaching the debugger). You can track [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3473) for when we hope for it to be ready.

Comment: Thanks Brett for your help and all your great work!